# Comparing user flows for products

Tags: users, comparison, flow

I am challenged with presenting 2+ applications & their user flows to my product partners as a bird's eye view. Some of the steps will be common & some unique to these products. The purpose is to highlight a common step- user validation that occurs across a few applications but at different points during the experience. Any suggestions on an elegant way to solve this? Here's a quick & dirty visual i came up with. Any thoughts on this representation will be helpful[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I think your example is good. It's simple and highlights the gaps well. What problems do you see with it? What more do you need to show?

Answer (score 0):

It's a good presentation idea. I would add more details into the flow such as: what devices will be used, what is the environment, perhaps some sketches of the user (storyboard). Basically, more context that allows stakeholders to empathize and understand the user better.